# Issue with using special character in JSON_VALUE of Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am running the following code on Oracle 12c :

```
DECLARE
           l_json clob;
           l_var varchar2(90);
BEGIN
           l_json := '{
                      "value>50": {
                        "id": "file",
                        "value": "55",
                        "popup": {
                          "menuitem": [{
                            "value": "New",
                            "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"
                          },
                          {
                            "value": "Open",
                            "onclick": "OpenDoc()"
                          },
                          {
                            "value": "Close",
                            "onclick": "CloseDoc()"
                          }]
                        }
                      }
                    }';

    SELECT JSON_VALUE(l_json, '$.value>50.value') INTO l_var FROM dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('var: '||l_var);
END;
```

While running it, i am getting the following error:

> Error report - 
>   ORA-06550: line 17, column 47: 
>   PL/SQL: ORA-40442: JSON path expression syntax error
>   ORA-06550: line 17, column 1:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

I am expecting result as: 
var: 55
Is there a way to use special characters in JSON_VALUE?

Comment: @AlexPoole No, i am referring to special character: '>' and the json path will be '$.value>50.value' to access the value: 55. Since, 'value>50' is one of the keys, hence using this in my json path.

Comment: Ah, I see, misread that. Might be useful to clarify that in the question though.

Comment: Although, [from the same doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#GUID-AEBAD813-99AB-418A-93AB-F96BC1658618): A key must start with an uppercase or lowercase letter A to Z and contain only such letters or decimal digits (0-9), or else it must be enclosed in double quotation marks ("). So does `'$."value>50".value` work?

Comment: It worked perfectly after adding quotation mark (")

Comment: @AlexPoole, is there a limitation to length of JSON passed in JSON_VALUE as well? in my original problem i am passing the JSON of 11000 charaters and it's not fetching the results for me.

Comment: Your JSON variable is a CLOB, so 11K isn't a problem. (You'd get an error it you tried to set the CLOB as you've shown if the string literal exceeded 32K, but that a different issue). You're putting the double-quotes around individual keys (with special chars), not  the whole path, right?

Comment: @AlexPoole, i am putting double-quotes around individual keys only and it works fine for small JSONs and since i am using CLOB to hold my JSON, can't i use JSONs with length more than 32K?

Comment: Yes, you can, that isn't an issue. It's creating the CLOB that's more work if it's large than that - you can't do a single assignment as you are now, you have to append data to the CLOB in chunks. That isn't the issue here though. Without seeing your large JSON and the path you're using, no idea why you don't get a match, sorry.

Comment: @AlexPoole, it worked fine after making `value>50` to `"value>50"`, but the same error came when i used `$."+9918898".value` as path it gives me the same exception. Any idea around that?

Comment: Works fine for me when I use that new pattern. (In 12.2, via Live SQL). Maybe ask a new question with the JSON and query you're using if you're sure that's what it's complaining about

Comment: @AlexPoole I am using ORACLE 12.1.0.2.0 version. It is still giving me the same error. Can you try with Oracle 12.1.0.2.0? Basically, any special character in the beginning of the key is giving me the same error.

Comment: Sorry, not at the moment. I don't think + has any special meaning, so I'd be surprised if a quoted value had an issue; but it's not impossible (e.g. see support doc 2123923.1 - it doesn't like having $ in the quoted key). You may need to raise a service request if this is reproducible.

Answer (score 5):

[The documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#GUID-AEBAD813-99AB-418A-93AB-F96BC1658618):

> An object step is a period (`.`), sometimes read as "dot", followed by an object key (object property name) or an asterisk (`*`) wildcard, which stands for (the values of) all keys. A key must start with an uppercase or lowercase letter A to Z and contain only such letters or decimal digits (0-9), or else it must be enclosed in double quotation marks (`"`).

So since your key includes the character `>`, which isn't one of the allowed ones listed, you need to quote it by changing your JSON path to:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(l_json, '$."value>50".value') INTO l_var FROM dual;
```